# iOS 7 Navigation Bar does not stay clear

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I want to have my navigation bar clear in iOS 7. I know this question has been asked before, but I cannot find an answer to the specific problem that I am having.  I set my navigation bar clear in my App Delegate using this code:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[navigationBarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

That works fine, my first navigation bar is clear. Then when I select a button and push a new view controller it gets a slight alpha increase on it. Looks like black with about 20% alpha. See picture here:

[image]

Then when i press the back button, the first view has the same slight alpha increase affect on it.

I have commented out ALL references to navigation bar in the second view controller to make sure I'm not accidentally changing something. I checked for differences in IB between the first and second view controllers and can't find anything there either. Tearing my hair out!

Comment: change the tint color to clearColor.

Comment: I have tried this as well

Answer (score 0):

try setting the translucent property to YES in viewDidAppear

```
navigationBarAppearance.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: What is `navigationBarAppearance` a property of?

Comment: @JeffN, its a property of UINavigationBar.h

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.navigationBarAppearance.translucent = YES;` giving me a "Property 'navigationBarAppearance' not found on object of type `UINavigationBar`

Comment: yup iOS 7. This works for me:  

    UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    navigationBarAppearance.translucent = YES;

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
navigationBarAppearance.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

As expected I was missing something in the code!

The view controller inherited from a custom view controller class that was setting an alpha onto the navigation bar.